# Is there a filter for enqueue script to strip the type="text/javascript" property

Tags: theme-development, wp-enqueue-script, html5

`script type="text/javascript"` is optional in HTML5 and all browsers (even old ones) recognize JavaScript without it. I am building an HTML5 site and want my script output to be consistent. However, scripts that use the WordPress enqueue function are printed with`type="text/javascript"`.

CSS is also printed with `type="text/css"`, which is also not needed.

I can't find a filter to remove those properties. Is there one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is hardcoded in `WP_Scripts->do_item()` method ( [source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.4/wp-includes/class.wp-scripts.php#L125) ) and probably same for styles. So it cannot be filtered.

As alternative you can extend class with modified version of this method and replace instance in global `$wp_scripts` variable.

Comment: Actually the style loader is a little better in that sense, you can hook onto `style_loader_tag` and adjust whatever parts of the link element(ie. `<link ="">` etc..) you like, there's unfortunately no equivalent for the script loader... :(

Comment: Rarst, can you elaborate on how to do this? Thanks

Comment: @envysea it's not something I would recommend doing in practice, _especially_ if you not up to implementing and maintaining such solution on updates.

Comment: Open issue in progress at https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/13592 ++ See also script_loader_src filter at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47206/how-can-i-remove-the-site-url-from-enqueued-scripts-and-styles