# How can I remove the site URL from enqueued scripts and styles?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-head

I'm dealing with an SSL issue and I would like to strip the domain from all scripts and styles being output via wp_enqueue_scripts. This would result in all scripts and styles being displayed with a relative path from the domain root.

I imagine there is a hook that I can use to fileter this, however, I am not sure which one, nor how to go about it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Similar to Wyck's answer, but using str_replace instead of regex.

`script_loader_src` and `style_loader_src` are the hooks you want.

```
<?php
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', 'wpse47206_src' );
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', 'wpse47206_src' );
function wpse47206_src( $url )
{
    if( is_admin() ) return $url;
    return str_replace( site_url(), '', $url );
}
```

You could also start the script/style URLs with a double slash `//` (a "[network path reference](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.2)").  Which might be safer (?): still has the full path, but uses the scheme/protocol of the current page.

```
<?php
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', 'wpse47206_src' );
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', 'wpse47206_src' );
function wpse47206_src( $url )
{
    if( is_admin() ) return $url;
    // why pass by reference on count? last arg
    return str_replace( array( 'http:', 'https:' ), '', $url, $c=1 );
}
```

Comment: Excellent, just the hooks I was looking for.

Comment: Any particular reason that you're excluding the admin section here?

Comment: @ElYobo Probably because you don't want to unexpectedly change HTML content you're about to edit and save.  Also note you can use wp-cli to do find and replace in the database as in: `wp search-replace 'http://mydomain.tld' 'https://mydomain.tld'`

Comment: @surfbuds The issue is not related to content, it's related to the scripts/styles loaded in code.  It won't affect content that you're about to edit and save and doing a search and replace in the database will likewise not solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, i think its possible. See on the filter hook `script_loader_src`; there get the string and you can filter this for your requirements.

```
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', 'fb_filter_script_loader', 1 );
function fb_filter_script_loader( $src ) {

    // remove string-part "?ver="
    $src = explode( '?ver=', $src );

    return $src[0];
}
```

- write on scratch, not tested

The same is possible for stylesheets, ther load via `wp_enqueue_style` with filter`style_loader_src`.

Answer (score 3):

Another way, which I think I got from the *roots* theme, maybe a bit ghetto but has some smart handling on when to use relative urls (tested only on dev site). The benefit is it can be uses as a filter on many other built in urls that WordPress uses. This example only shows style and script enqueue filter.

```
function roots_root_relative_url($input) {
  $output = preg_replace_callback(
    '!(https?://[^/|"]+)([^"]+)?!',
    create_function(
      '$matches',
      // if full URL is site_url, return a slash for relative root
      'if (isset($matches[0]) && $matches[0] === site_url()) { return "/";' .
      // if domain is equal to site_url, then make URL relative
      '} elseif (isset($matches[0]) && strpos($matches[0], site_url()) !== false) { return $matches[2];' .
      // if domain is not equal to site_url, do not make external link relative
      '} else { return $matches[0]; };'
    ),
    $input
  );

  /**
   * Fixes an issue when the following is the case:
   * site_url() = http://yoursite.com/inc
   * home_url() = http://yoursite.com
   * WP_CONTENT_DIR = http://yoursite.com/content
   * http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Moving_wp-content
   */
  $str = "/" . end(explode("/", content_url()));
  if (strpos($output, $str) !== false) {
    $arrResults = explode( $str, $output );
    $output = $str . $arrResults[1];
  }

  return $output;

if (!is_admin()) {
  add_filter('script_loader_src', 'roots_root_relative_url');
  add_filter('style_loader_src', 'roots_root_relative_url');
 }
```